# ClickOnce not auto-updating from start menu

Tags: wpf, clickonce, auto-update

We currently have a WPF application that is deployed using ClickOnce on a file server within our corporate network. It is set to auto update before the application starts, it is allowed to run offline (in case the file server goes down for some reason), and we ticked "Create desktop icon".

In our CI Build we inject the versioning, and we have tried to incremenet different parts of the version number to try to force the change. This has had no effect.

If the user tries to run the application from the start menu or the desktop shortcut, it never auto-updates.

If we delete the desktop shortcut, right click the .application file on the server and select "Send to Desktop", the resulting desktop shortcut *will* auto update without fail.

Has anyone experienced this issue, and if so how was it resolved?

Our interim solution is to delete the shortcut created in the initial install, and manually create the shortcut as described above, but it feels like a bit of a hack!

Edited: Added more info as per Karel's comment.

Comment: ClickOnce only updates the app when it detects a changed version, are you changing the version number of the app? There's an option to automatically increment the version number whenever you publish.

Comment: We actually increment it using a script, and tried doing it manually as well. Edited the original post to include that information.

Comment: Open Fiddler, try to launch the app from Start Menu. Check Fiddler to see if it's hitting the server.

Comment: Enable Clickonce logging and see the real cause of the issue. It might well be that the assembly identify has changed in the manifest and runtime is rejecting the new update even though it can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the shortcut in a text editor and see it is refers to location that exists. I had the same problem and the shortcut referred to a non existent local share. This did not stop my ClickOnce application from starting, only without updates.